# I need to decipher a username and password but keep getting internal server error from node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cryptojs

I am stumped as to why my node server throws an error 500 when trying to decipher a username and password from a axios post request from a ReactJS app.

Here is my React code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Jumbotron } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "../styled-components/button";
import { ButtonBase } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Fade } from "react-reveal";
import axios from "axios";
import { createCipheriv, randomBytes } from "crypto";
//create random 16bytes
let iv = "NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/A";
//encryption key that is used
let key = "gVkYp3s6v8y/B?E(H+MbQeThWmZq4t7w";

export default function Login(props) {
  //set State for the user application
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  //set error message state if data returned is invalid
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
  //create handlers for state change and assign value to the state
  const handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };
  //handle submission to the server
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //start encryption process
    let cipher = createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    //username encryption
    let encryptedUsername = cipher.update(username, "utf-8", "hex");
    encryptedUsername += cipher.final("hex");
    //password encryption process
    let encryptedPassword = cipher.update(password, "utf-8", "hex");
    encryptedPassword += cipher.final("hex");

    console.log(encryptedUsername + " " + encryptedPassword);
    //post the encrypted data to the server
    axios
      .post("/users", {
        username: encryptedUsername,
        password: encryptedPassword,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        //receive the response from the server and mark the username & password correct/invalid
        if (res.data === "invalid") {
          setError(true);
          //if username and password are valid, then transfer user to the home page and create a session
        } else if (
          encryptedUsername === res.data[0].username &&
          encryptedPassword === res.data[0].password
        ) {
          //window.location = "/home";
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Fade>
      <Container style={{ marginTop: "5%" }}>
        <Row>
          <Col lg={12} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <h3>Please Login to see all your daily To-Do Tasks</h3>
          </Col>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
              <Jumbotron>
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Label>Username:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      onChange={handleUsernameChange}
                      placeholder="Username:"
                      value={username}
                      required
                    ></Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Label>Password:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                      onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                      placeholder="Password:"
                      value={password}
                      required
                      type="password"
                    ></Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                    {error ? (
                      <Fade>
                        <b style={{ color: "red" }}>
                          Invalid username or password
                        </b>
                      </Fade>
                    ) : (
                      <></>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row style={{ marginTop: "5%" }}>
                  <Col>
                    <ButtonBase style={{ float: "right" }}>
                      <Button
                        color="primary"
                        style={{ float: "right" }}
                        type="submit"
                      >
                        Login
                      </Button>
                    </ButtonBase>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col style={{ marginTop: "5%" }}>
                    <p style={{ float: "right" }}>
                      Need to register?{" "}
                      <a href="https://google.com/"> click here</a>
                    </p>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Jumbotron>
            </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Fade>
  );
}
```

and now here is my node.js express code for handling that request:

I updated the methods and placed two functions in to be called when the username and password lands, i have noticed that the username is logging and is a string, but when i try to log my password after it deciphers it shows up in strange characters, so there must be an issue with the password decipher method because when i log on my server what the typeof is for password, it shows that it is a string, and it shows that it is corresponding with the encrypted password being sent from the client side but when once it goes through the decipher method it scrambles it up and spits out those strange characters.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require("../database/connection");
const logger = require("../logger/logger");
const crypto = require("crypto");
//create initial vector
let iv = "NcRfUjXn2r5u8x/A";
//create the crypto key for deciphering the username/password
let key = "gVkYp3s6v8y/B?E(H+MbQeThWmZq4t7w";
/* GET users listing. */
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);

  let reqUser = req.body.username;
  let reqPass = req.body.pass;

  function decryptUsername() {
    //create decipcher API
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    //decipher the username before sending it to MySQL
    let decryptedUsername = decipher.update(reqUser, "hex", "utf-8");
    decryptedUsername += decipher.final("utf-8");

    console.log(decryptedUsername);

    return decryptedUsername;
  }

  function decryptPassword() {
    //create decipcher API
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    //decipher the password before sending it to MySQL
    let decryptedPassword = decipher.update(reqPass, "hex", "utf-8");
    decryptedPassword += decipher.final("utf-8");

    console.log(typeof decryptedPassword);

    return decryptedPassword;
  }

  let username = decryptUsername(reqUser);
  console.log(username);

  let password = decryptPassword(reqPass);

  //Establish connection to MySQL Database
  connection.getConnection((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    //MySQL database query to check username & password exists
    connection.query(
      "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",
      [username, password],
      function (err, results) {
        if (results.length === 0) {
          //log the credentails that are invalid/un-authenticated
          logger.log({
            level: "error",
            message: `failed user login: username: ${username} password: ${password}`,
          });
          //send invalid response to let the server know that credentials are incorrect
          res.send("invalid");
        } else {
          //logger to log access control to the access.log file
          logger.log({
            level: "info",
            message: `user ${username} logged in at:`,
          });
          //send response to user
          console.log(results);
          res.send(results);
        }
      }
    );
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

my encrypted data gets sent through correctly too and both server and client side are sharing a static key and initialization vector, but when i try decipher on my server side, it just throws a error 500

any help will be much appreciated :)

here is a snippet of the server error[POST /users 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDRMA.png)

this is when i console.log(decipher)

[logging the decipher method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaDue.png)

[Strange characters that it is spitting out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q3u7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found the issue that causing my ciphered password to be parsed into strange characters, i had to create a module for each cipher and decipher method, pass the values to the decipher modules and then return the value, now it is working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

1. You should use useEffect to make all rest calls. If you need how to make, I have a sample repo, I can share that.
2. where is /users path on the server route?
3. you should have res.send at the last. Logging also you need to have above that. Otherwise, you will get a warning/error on the server-side.
4. How do you know decipher is giving 500 error? any error msg you see?

Comment: When i remove the decipher code block, the server will the proceed to MySQL and do the corresponding queries, from there on my app side i receive a "Invalid username or password" as the username and password do not match to the ciphered ones

Comment: please print response of this `crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);`

Comment: please see the newly attached screenshot